# Create folders on master node if don't exist

Tags: ansible

I need to run task that would check and create if missing folders on Ansible Control Node (where the `ansible-playbook` command is run) - next tasks will copy some specified files respectively to these local sub-folders:

I have a task:

```yaml
   tasks:
     - name: Create local directory
       file:
        path: "remotes/{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        state: directory
        recurse: yes
       delegate_to: localhost
       tags:
         localfolders
```

however when I run with `--check` it is going to "change" (create folders) on each remote:

```
TASK [Create local directory] ****************************************************************************************************************
changed: [ansible -> localhost]
changed: [remote1 -> localhost]
changed: [remote2 -> localhost]
```

Why it not runs task on local only?

Expected result is that on ansible host (only), following folders are created:

```
remotes/ansible
remotes/remote1
remotes/remote2
```

Comment: `Why it not runs task on local only` <= it does but it will fire a run (delegated to localhost as visually reported by `-> localhost`) for every target in your play hosts loop. What you are missing here is `run_once: true` on your task. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#running-on-a-single-machine-with-run-once

Answer (score 0):

To get a better understand of [Controlling where tasks run: delegation and local actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) and [`run_once`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#running-on-a-single-machine-with-run-once) works, I've prepared a small test with an `inventory` file of

```
[test]
remote01.example.com
remote02.example.com
```

and a playbook `local.yml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: Check where I am running on
      delegate_to: localhost
      shell:
        cmd:  "hostname && hostname -i"
      register: result
      run_once: true

    - name: Show result
      debug:
        msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
      run_once: false
```

executed on `control.example.com` node via

```
sshpass -p ${PASSWORD} ansible-playbook --user ${ACCOUNT} --ask-pass local.yml
```

resulting into an output of

```
PLAY [test] ********************************

TASK [Check where I am running on] *********
changed: [remote01.example.com -> localhost]

TASK [Show result] *************************
ok: [remote01.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - control.example.com
  - 192.0.2.1
ok: [remote02.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - control.example.com
  - 192.0.2.1

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************
remote01.example.com : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
remote02.example.com : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**Interesting Doc**

- [IPv4 Address Blocks Reserved for Documentation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5737)